# gravity forms calculation jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is there a way to integrate a simple jquery function to gravity forms?

I have 3 fields that I need to use with.

2 number fields and 1 total field, total will be calculated based on the number fields.

Here is the script, I managed to make it work but there is no ajax and the total field is just showing the number and not the $price.

```
function calc_price()
    { 
        var sr = parseInt($("#d_start_rating").val());
        if(!sr){
            sr = 0;
            $("#d_start_rating").val(sr);
        } 
        var er = parseInt($("#d_end_rating").val());
        if(!er){
            er = 0;
            $("#d_end_rating").val(er);
        } 

        if(er > 6000){er = 6000}
        var points = 0;

ranges = {"2500":0.09,"3000":0.11,"3500":0.15,"4000":0.21,"4500":0.27,"5000":0.35,"5500":0.45,"6000":0.8};
        //var ranges = {2500: 0.08, 3000: 0.11, 3500: 0.14, 4000: 0.20, 4500: 0.24, 5000: 0.30, 5500: 0.35, 6000: 0.6};
        for(var key in ranges){
            if(sr >= er){break;}
            if(key > er){
                points += (er-sr)*ranges[key];
                sr = er;
                break;
            }
            if(sr < key){
                points += (key - sr) * ranges[key];
                sr = key;
            }
        }
        points = Math.ceil(points);
        $(".a_points").html(points);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#d_start_rating').change(function() {
            calc_price();
        });
        $('#d_end_rating').change(function() {
            calc_price();
        });

        calc_price();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for the [gform_post_render](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_post_render/) JS event. You can bind your custom functionality to this event rather than the document ready event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){

    $('#d_start_rating').change(function() {
        calc_price();
    });

    $('#d_end_rating').change(function() {
        calc_price();
    });

    calc_price();

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response David, ill definitely try that out.

Comment: That does not work, the price is not getting updated if I won't go to the next page or use some field to refresh the page.